# How to manage a find in a recursive model with CakePHP?

Tags: cakephp, recursion, model, find

I have a standard recursive table of `categories`, each category can have a `parent category`; how could I perform a `find` to retrieve the entire categories structure?

I tried changing the `recursive` property but it's limited to 2 levels. Is there a way to do it with purely CakePHP functions/attributes or do I have to write a function and recreate the entire structure by myself?

Cheers,
Nicolas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

why don't you have a look at the tree behavior? It should do you what you're after! Read up at http://book.cakephp.org/view/1339/Tree

Comment: Oh, I've never seen it before! Thank you :)